# Contactscript.php not returning fields

Tags: php, email

I am getting an odd quirk with my basic contact script, forwarding form data to my mail.

I'm trying to get the form to forward the four input fields to my email, but so far, I'm getting only 'phone' and 'message', and any attempts to add $email & $name will result in the user not being directed to the thanks.php. Here's the script:

```
<?php

// VALUES FROM THE FORM

$name       = $_POST['name'];

$email      = $_POST['email'];

$message    = $_POST['msg'];

$phone      = $_POST['phone'];


// ERROR & SECURITY CHECKS

if ( ( !$email ) ||

     ( strlen($_POST['email']) > 200 ) ||

     ( !preg_match("#^[A-Za-z0-9](([_\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)@([A-Za-z0-9]+)(([\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)\.([A-Za-z]{2,})$#", $email) )

   ) 

{ 

    print "Error: Invalid E-Mail Address"; 

    exit; 

} 

if ( ( !$name ) ||

     ( strlen($name) > 100 ) ||

     ( preg_match("/[:=@\<\>]/", $name) ) 

   )

{ 

    print "Error: Invalid Name"; 

    exit; 

} 

if ( preg_match("#cc:#i", $message, $matches) )

{ 

    print "Error: Found Invalid Header Field"; 

    exit; 

} 

if ( !$message )

{

    print "Error: No Message"; 

    exit; 

} 

if (eregi("\r",$email) || eregi("\n",$email)){ 

    print "Error: Invalid E-Mail Address"; 

    exit; 

} 

if (FALSE) { 

    print "Error: You cannot send to an email address on the same domain."; 

    exit; 

} 





// CREATE THE EMAIL

$headers    = "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit";     // rivi kertoo, että käytät merkkejä, jotka ovat perus 7-bittisen US-ASCII:n ulkopuolella (esim. skandeja)
$headers    .= "From: $name <$email>\n";

$recipient  = "email@email.com";

$subject    = "Asiakkaan yhteydenotto";

$message    = wordwrap($message, 1024);

$phone      = wordwrap($phone, 1024);


// SEND THE EMAIL TO YOU
$message = "Phone: $phone\r\n" . $message;
mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers);



// REDIRECT TO THE THANKS PAGE

header("location: thanks.php");

?>
```

What am I doing wrong, here? I need those names and emails from potential customers.

Comment: First things first. I don't see your form, so are your inputs named?

Comment: Aye. The four input fields in the HTML-form are named 'name', 'email', 'phone', 'msg'- respectively. EDIT: Ah, right- I forgot to mention, it seems that the 'sender' is overwritten by the webhost forward address sending the e-mail to it's target location.

Comment: Try `$message = "Phone: " . $phone . "\n" . "Email: " . $email . "\n" . "Message: " . $message . "\n";`

Comment: And also `$headers .= "From: $name <$email>\r\n";` which could also be an issue. But try my first suggestion before doing this.

Comment: I tested my answer below which worked. Give it a try.

Comment: Ah! That seems to have done it, many thanks, Fred the Second! Also added the $name field input in similar fashion, and now it returns all values successfully. I really need to brush up on my php, it seems.

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help. Let's close the question properly and click the white checkmark next to my answer till it turns green, otherwise it will remain in the unanswered category. Cheers ;-) and welcome to SO.

Comment: ^-- cuz that's how she rolls ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This worked for me:**

I changed your: (as per my comment)

```
$message = "Phone: $phone\r\n" . $message;
```

To:

```
$message = "Phone: " . $phone . "\n" . "Email: " . $email . "\n" . "Message: " . $message . "\n";
```

(Rewrite)

```
<?php

// VALUES FROM THE FORM

$name       = $_POST['name'];
$email      = $_POST['email'];
$message    = $_POST['msg'];
$phone      = $_POST['phone'];

// ERROR & SECURITY CHECKS

if ( ( !$email ) ||

     ( strlen($_POST['email']) > 200 ) ||

     ( !preg_match("#^[A-Za-z0-9](([_\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)@([A-Za-z0-9]+)(([\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)\.([A-Za-z]{2,})$#", $email) )

   ) 

{ 

    print "Error: Invalid E-Mail Address"; 

    exit; 

} 

if ( ( !$name ) ||

     ( strlen($name) > 100 ) ||

     ( preg_match("/[:=@\<\>]/", $name) ) 

   )

{ 

    print "Error: Invalid Name"; 

    exit; 

} 

if ( preg_match("#cc:#i", $message, $matches) )

{ 

    print "Error: Found Invalid Header Field"; 

    exit; 

} 

if ( !$message )

{

    print "Error: No Message"; 

    exit; 

} 

if (eregi("\r",$email) || eregi("\n",$email)){ 

    print "Error: Invalid E-Mail Address"; 

    exit; 

} 

if (FALSE) { 

    print "Error: You cannot send to an email address on the same domain."; 

    exit; 

} 

// CREATE THE EMAIL

$headers    = "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit";     // rivi kertoo, että käytät merkkejä, jotka ovat perus 7-bittisen US-ASCII:n ulkopuolella (esim. skandeja)
$headers    .= "From: $name <$email>\n";

$recipient  = "email@email.com";

$subject    = "Asiakkaan yhteydenotto";
$message    = wordwrap($message, 1024);
$phone      = wordwrap($phone, 1024);


// SEND THE EMAIL TO YOU
// $message = "Phone: $phone\r\n" . $message;

$message = "Phone: " . $phone . "\n" . "Email: " . $email . "\n" . "Message: " . $message . "\n";

mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers);


// REDIRECT TO THE THANKS PAGE

header("location: thanks.php");


?>
```